# Find the projection of a vector onto a subspace of $\Bbb R^4$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, vectors, multilinear-algebra

I need to find the projection of $\vec b = (1,1,1,1)$ onto a subspace of $\Bbb R^4$ described as:

$$V=\{(x,y,z,t)\,:\,x=y+t\ \hbox{and}\ 2x=y+z\}\ .$$

Thanks for any help i get guys.

Answer (score 1):

First find a basis for $V$.  We have
$$\eqalign{V
  &=\{\,(x,y,2x-y,x-y)\mid x,y\in{\Bbb R}\,\}\cr
  &=\mathop{\rm span}\{\,(1,0,2,1),\,(0,1,-1,-1)\,\}\ ,\cr}$$
and so
$$\def\v#1{{\bf #1}}
  \v w_1=(1,0,2,1)\ ,\quad \v w_2=(0,1,-1,-1)$$
form a basis for $V$.  Now the projection of $\v b$ onto $V$ is
$$\lambda_1\v w_1+\lambda_2\v w_2\ ,\tag{$*$}$$
where
$$\v b=\lambda_1\v w_1+\lambda_2\v w_2+\v w\tag{$*{*}$}$$
and $\v w$ is perpendicular to $V$.  (If you can't see why, draw a picture.)  Now calculating the dot product of $(*{*})$ with $\v w_1$ and remembering that $\v w\cdot\v w_1=0$ gives you an equation for $\lambda_1,\lambda_2$.  Calculating the dot product with $\v w_2$ gives another.  Solve for $\lambda_1,\lambda_2$ and substitute back into $(*)$.

Good luck!

Comment: I'm confused on what you mean when you say take the dot product of b with $w_1$. I know what the dot product is, but i don't know how i would take it.

Comment: See revised answer.